# Is [suggestions-wanted] appropriate on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, off-topic, software-engineering-se

There are currently 21 [questions on Stack Overflow tagged [tag:suggestions-wanted]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/suggestions-wanted). They are mostly in the *"Help me pick a project"* vein.

I've always found those kinds of questions troubling because they seem to be either too broad
 (*give me something **cool** to do*) or too narrow (*help **me** pick a final project for **my** class*) and sometimes both. Moreover, to the extent that they are good questions (lots of people have these kinds of questions and they do attract interest), they seem to be *people* questions rather than code questions.

I'd just as soon see them pushed to Programmers, and let that site sort out when to allow them and how to handle the steady stream.

Thoughts?

Comment: I agree, these really would fit better on Programmers.  I typically tell people to talk to their professors, advisors, and fellow students when I see these types of questions, as those groups of people have a lot more relevant information to go on than we do.

Answer (score 4):

They certainly don't belong on SO. I don't think they're even right for Programmers SE, though. You could ask "help me pick my next project" as a painter or a hot rod enthusiast or a chef.

If it's not an objective question or a "[good subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)" question, take it away from Stack Exchange. [suggestions-wanted](/questions/tagged/suggestions-wanted) questions are certainly not the former and likely not the latter.

Comment: I could go for this, but I sometime feel I'm a Grinch around here...always saying *"We don't want your kind [of questions] 'round here."* and *"Get off mah lawn!"*. And they are popular at times, so I didn't want to stake to strong a position.

Answer (score 1):

Most of these either don't warrant [suggestions-wanted](/questions/tagged/suggestions-wanted) or belong on programmers.SE.

I think this tag should be banned.

Comment: Why would we ban a tag instead of just shutting those questions down?

Comment: @Lance if there are no cases where that tag is OK then we should ban it.